# SQL Server 2012 installation - Service 'SQLBrowser' start request failed

Tags: windows, installation, sql-server

I am having trouble installing SQL Server 2012 Express on Windows 7. Whenever I try the installation, I get the error

> Service 'SQLBrowser' start request failed.

If I click Retry, it happens again. When I click Cancel, the installation aborts.

When I try to manually start the SQL Server Browser service from Control Panel, I get the message

> The SQL Server Browser service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

I can start the SQL Server service fine, but I can't connect to it. I am surprised it is even there, since the installation aborted.

I had SQL Server 2005 Express installed when I first tried installing 2012. I uninstalled 2005, and I still couldn't install 2012.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hacking around for a while, I have got it installed. I'm not sure what was causing it, but I tried to use the default setup options as much as possible, and it worked.